# Sample backup Script

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to run a simple backup script and it's only printing error message. Is there something I doing wrong? Here's the complete code. I'm on linux and have full access to the database.

It only prints 'There was an issue with your system that prevented the backup from completing'

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost"; // usually localhost
$dbuser = "myuser";
$dbpass = "mypass";
$dbname = "mydb";
$sendto = "Webmaster <webmaster@mydomain.com>";
$sendfrom = "Automated Backup <info@mydomain.com>";
$sendsubject = "Daily Mysql Backup";
$bodyofemail = "Here is the daily backup.";


$headers = 'My Shop <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";

$backupfile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d") . '.sql';

if(system("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > $backupfile")){
   mail('receiver@yahoo.com','Back Up Service','Back Up successfully completed',$headers );
      echo'Back up saved successfully.';
  }else {
    echo'There was an issue with your system that prevented the backup from completing';
   }
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error message is it printing:  the one in your code, or something else/lower level?

Comment: It's printing the error in my code

Comment: Just so you know, if you're on a shared server, your MySQL password is going to be available to every other user on that server if they want to look at the process list.

Comment: They should only give jailed access on a shared server though @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be something wrong with your command:

```
mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > $backupfile
```

This looks fine but it's worth printing it out so that you can check it in the command line to see what result you get.

Edit:
Looking at the system docs available here: [system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) it looks like this returns the last line of the commands output. If mysqldump runs sucessfully but doesn't create any output your `if` will return false. Either use:

```
if(system("mysqldump blah blah") === false){
```

or use the return_var argument to system to check the status code (it should be 0 on success).

Comment: Ha, looks like it's backing up, but the email is not firing, so what might be the problem?

Comment: Take the email code out into a separate script and run it by itself to debug the problem.

Comment: @HelenNeely I've updated my answer. The problem is probably the if statement.

Comment: Thanks Jim, you've been marvellous. Your code above solved the problem. :)